# Removing consecutive occurreneces of certain letters

Tags: java, regex

Hey I am trying to remove any consecutive occurrences certain but not all letters, can anyone see what I am doing wrong please?

```
  result2 = result2.replaceAll("[aeioucgjkqsxyzbfpvwdtmn]\\1+", "$1");
```

Comment: Note that you can reduce your character class to: `[a-gijkm-qs-z]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the group in your regex.

Try this instead:

```
result2 = result2.replaceAll("([aeioucgjkqsxyzbfpvwdtmn])\\1+", "$1");
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/pO8fO6